# sys.stdout does not have attribute flush in bpython

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys, bpython

I am using bpython for interactive Python sessions and since I updated my system I have the following problem:

In bpython3:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.flush
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'FakeStream' object has no attribute 'flush'
```

However, in Python3:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.flush
<built-in method flush of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x7fab6b7fb708>
```

The same for IPython3.

So why does `sys.stdout` not have the attribute `flush` in bpython3? I searched for the source code of the `sys` module, but couldn't find it. Nor could I find a `sysmodule.c` file or something like that. Doesn't bpython use the same code for this module as the other CLIs?

```
$ bpython3 --version
bpython version 0.12 on top of Python 3.4.2
(C) 2008-2012 Bob Farrell, Andreas Stuehrk et al. See AUTHORS for detail.

$ python3 --version
Python 3.4.2
```

Comment: does `sys.__stdout__.flush` work?

Comment: This indeed does work in `bpython3`, @PadraicCunningham

Comment: seems to be a bug that was fixed in version 0.13 http://docs.bpython-interpreter.org/changelog.html?highlight=fakestream#id4  `pip3 install -U bpython` should fix the issue

Comment: Great, thank you. It fixed the issue. For completeness, the commit where this bug was fixed: [Github](https://github.com/bpython/bpython/commit/570239387c25a1e5213ce8cee5d4e47ab76033cb)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, sure, done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug that was fixed in version  [0.13](http://docs.bpython-interpreter.org/changelog.html?highlight=fakestream#id4).

Upgrading with  `pip3 install -U bpython` should update to the latest stable release which includes the fix.